# Open-source, thread-safe implementation of convex optimization solvers in C/C++?

Tags: optimization, c

Is there an open-source, thread-safe implementation of convex optimization solvers in C/C++?

Some libraries such as [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt), [Ipopt](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt), [OPT++](https://software.sandia.gov/opt++/) don't meet my requirements.

OPT++ and Ipopt aren't thread-safe, and NLopt doesn't seem to have a specific/efficient way to solve convex programming problems with equality/inequality constraints.

Comment: can you tell us what about those libraries won't work for you?

Comment: @GodricSeer I just edited my question.

Comment: Could you explain your thread-safe requirement? If you use IPOPT with a parallel linear solver then you parallelize at the bottleneck. Or why would you like to have multiple threads? How would you like to use the solver?

Comment: @Ali I want to run separate solvers in different threads.

Comment: @TianyangLi OK, I see, in this case IPOPT really would not work for you, you are right. Upvoted your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I contacted [OBOE](https://projects.coin-or.org/OBOE)'s developers, they said [it's thread-safe](http://list.coin-or.org/pipermail/oboe/2012-September/000015.html).